# NGINX - dlopen() "ngx_http_lua_module.so" failed (libluajit-5.1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx, lua, luajit

Am out of choices right now with this tries, (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
**Installing LuaJIT 2.0.5**

```
==== Successfully built LuaJIT 2.0.5 ====
    ==== Installing LuaJIT 2.0.5 to /usr/local ====
    mkdir -p /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include/luajit-2.0 /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.5/jit /usr/local/share/lua/5.1 /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1
    cd src && install -m 0755 luajit /usr/local/bin/luajit-2.0.5
    cd src && test -f libluajit.a && install -m 0644 libluajit.a /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.a || :
    rm -f /usr/local/bin/luajit /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2.0.5 /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2
    cd src && test -f libluajit.so && \
      install -m 0755 libluajit.so /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2.0.5 && \
      ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib && \
      ln -sf libluajit-5.1.so.2.0.5 /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so && \
      ln -sf libluajit-5.1.so.2.0.5 /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2 || :
    cd etc && install -m 0644 luajit.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1
    cd etc && sed -e "s|^prefix=.*|prefix=/usr/local|" -e "s|^multilib=.*|multilib=lib|" luajit.pc > luajit.pc.tmp && \
      install -m 0644 luajit.pc.tmp /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/luajit.pc && \
      rm -f luajit.pc.tmp
    cd src && install -m 0644 lua.h lualib.h lauxlib.h luaconf.h lua.hpp luajit.h /usr/local/include/luajit-2.0
    cd src/jit && install -m 0644 bc.lua v.lua dump.lua dis_x86.lua dis_x64.lua dis_arm.lua dis_ppc.lua dis_mips.lua dis_mipsel.lua bcsave.lua vmdef.lua /usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.5/jit
    ln -sf luajit-2.0.5 /usr/local/bin/luajit
    ==== Successfully installed LuaJIT 2.0.5 to /usr/local ====
```

Then, tried starting but same error.

```
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
```

So again googled a bit and got below fix, but seems no effect,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
```

No luck still, What am i missing, Please help.

Comment: It is not clear what is your goal. Why do you think LuaJIT is related to nginx? Maybe all you need is OpenResty bundle?

Comment: Yes i might have need openresty and now am installed openresty bundle and got this exception, https://github.com/openresty/openresty/issues/587